# getView makes scrolling unsmooth

Tags: android, android-listview, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying load images off the web (as well as some text not off the web) and display them in a `listview`. The problem is, that the `listview` getting messed up. some cells are switching quickly and it messing up the `listView` order.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null)
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.coin_layout, parent, false);
        //find the coin to work with.
        Coin currentCoin = coins.get(position);

        //fill the view
        try {
            //   ImageView coinIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinIcon);
            //   coinIcon.setTag(currentCoin.getImageLink());

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.position = position;
            holder.coinIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinIcon);
            holder.coinName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinName);
            holder.coinPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinPrice);
            holder.coinPercentage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinPercentage);
            holder.currentCoin = currentCoin;


            //  holder.coinIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coinIcon);

            // Using an AsyncTask to load the slow images in a background thread
            new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
                private ViewHolder v;
                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
                    v = params[0];
                    Log.d("V log", v.currentCoin.getName());

                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    try{
                        URL ulrn = new URL(v.currentCoin.getImageLink());
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
                        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                        if (null != bmp)
                            return bmp;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}
                    return bmp;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    if (v.position == position) {
                        Log.d("V Posion ", "" + v.position);
                        // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
                        // progress and set and show the image
                        //   v.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        v.coinIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        v.coinIcon.setImageBitmap(result);

                        v.typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
                        v.coinName.setText(v.currentCoin.getName());
                        v.coinPrice.setText("" + v.currentCoin.getPrice());
                        v.coinPercentage.setText(v.currentCoin.getPercentage());
                    }
                }
            }.execute(holder);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return itemView;
    }
```

Comment: Try using http://square.github.io/picasso/ to handle your image loading.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `getView()` will be called for each list-item and on there your are allocating the `ViewHolder()` every time, whether you can reuse the already created `ViewHolder()`. Also i will oppose the `AsyncTask()` inside the `getView()` rather you can use  [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library for lazy loading of the image on listView, which is very popular and regularly updated.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (itemView == null){
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.coin_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    }
        Coin currentCoin = coins.get(position);
    try {
        holder.position = position;
        //... rest of the code



        //... rest of the code
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create asyncTasks on every getView. What you see is a result of images finishing loading after the view is being reused or in random order. Look into ThreadPoolExecutor service.